# Taking the average of two Convolutional Neural Networks to get concept that is 'in the middle'

Tags: conv-neural-network

Suppose you have two Convolutional Neural Networks that are equal in design, but differ in what they are trained on. One is trained on Cats, the other on Dogs.

You could invert the networks to check what they have actually 'understood' of the dog/cat concept:

- [Understanding Deep Image Representation by Inverting Them](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0035v1.pdf)
- [Inverting Visual Representations with Convulutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02753.pdf)
- [Deep Inside Convolutional Networks: Visulising Image Classification Models and Saliency maps](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6034v2.pdf)
- [Inceptionism: Going deeper into Neural networks](https://research.googleblog.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html)

Resulting in images like this:
[image]

If you were to create a third CNN in which the weights/synapses are the average of the 'cat network' and 'dog network', would inverting this network result in images of 'catdogs?' (or whatever is conceptually in the middle). In other words, does it make sense to average two CNN's?

Comment: As long as the cnn's had the same structure, one would be talking about the weights.  It would make mathematical sense to average the weights.  However, if I took two pictures of different people, would I expect superimposition to give a picture of a third person ?

Comment: Well, explained like that. The average of a black square and a black circle would be a grey circle and a grey square in that case?